# Change specific columns as factor in R

Tags: r

I have a file name `"Second"`
and it has data `"q1","q2",...."q40"`, and `"q40_n1", "q40_n2","q40_n3", ..."q40_n20"`

Some of them are `"character"` vectors and some are `"integer"`

My question is How can I change integer vector to `"factor"` at once?

1. q30:q35 to "factor" ------- (q(30+n))
2. q40_n1:q40_n4 to "factor" ---------(q40_n#)
3. q18:q23 to "factor"

Comment: why  do you need as a factor ? what is the goal ?

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` package:

```
mutate_at(Second, vars(q30:q35, q40_n1:q40_n4, q18:q23), factor)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control all columns on read-in using the `colClasses=` argument:

```r
str(read.csv(text="a,b\na,1"))
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: Factor w/ 1 level "a": 1
#  $ b: int 1

str(read.csv(text="a,b\na,1", colClasses="factor"))
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: Factor w/ 1 level "a": 1
#  $ b: Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1

str(read.csv(text="a,b\na,1", colClasses="character"))
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: chr "a"
#  $ b: chr "1"
```

Or you can `factor`ize it later:

```r
dat <- read.csv(text="a,b\na,11")
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: Factor w/ 1 level "a": 1
#  $ b: int 11
dat$b <- factor(dat$b)
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: Factor w/ 1 level "a": 1
#  $ b: Factor w/ 1 level "11": 1

### or all columns, without regard to original class
dat <- read.csv(text="a,b\na,11")
dat[] <- lapply(dat, factor)
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ a: Factor w/ 1 level "a": 1
#  $ b: Factor w/ 1 level "11": 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A numeric or integer vector like:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
> str(x)
 num [1:3] 1 2 3
```

can be converted to a factor vector:

```
x <- as.factor(x)
> x
[1] 1 2 3
Levels: 1 2 3
> str(x)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
```